Bogoliubov approximation and the condensate wavefunction
I am trying to understand Bogoliubov's microscopic theory on weakly interacting Bose gases[Bogoliubov, 1947]. The Hamiltonian for N particles is: 
\begin{align} H=\sum_i [\frac{p_i^2}{2m}+V_{ext}(r_i)]+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j}V(r_i-r_j) \end{align}
where $V_{ext}$ is an external potential field and $V$ is the interacting potential between particles.
The field operator $\Psi(r)$ that annihilates a particle at position $r$ can be represented as the following:
\begin{align} \Psi(r)=\sum_n\langle r\rvert n\rangle a_n \end{align}
where {$\lvert n\rangle$} is the set of eigenstates of the single-particle Hamiltonian $H_s=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V_{ext}(r)$ and $a_n$ is the annihilating operator corresponding to $\lvert n\rangle$. In the Bogoliubov approximation, we assume that $\lvert 0\rangle$ is macroscopically occupied. Therefore, we regard $a_0$ as a number $\sqrt{N_0}$ and $\sum_{n\neq0}\langle r\rvert n\rangle a_n$ as a perturbation.
However, I found the following explanation in 110 page of the book 'Superconductivity, Superfluids and Condensates' written by Annett:

Bogoliubov introduced an elegant method to achieve this. He assumed that the field operators can be expressed approximately as their constant coherent state value, plus a small deviation, 
\begin{align} \Psi(r)=\psi_0(r)+\delta\psi(r) \end{align}

On the same page, Annett also states that $\psi_0(r)$ is a solution of the following Gross-Pitaevskii equation:
\begin{align} (-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V_{ext}(r)+V_{eff}-\mu)\psi_0(r)=0 \end{align}
\begin{align} V_{eff}(r)=\int V(r-r')\lvert\psi_0(r)\rvert^2 dr \end{align}
I was confused because there were no statements about 'coherent state' in Bogoliubov's original paper and above all, $\psi_0(r)$ is a solution of Gross-Pitaevskii equation, not $\langle r\rvert 0\rangle$.
My questions are the following:
1. In the Bogoliubov approximation, what state is macroscopically occupied? $\lvert 0\rangle$ or the coherent state corresponding to $\psi_0 (r)$?
2. Then what is the condensate wavefunction? $\psi_0(r)$ or $\langle r\rvert 0\rangle$?
